# Vue 3 data.name from api is undefined in script setup() but rendered in template

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am still new to Vue and have trouble with uing data from api within the script setup() of Vue3 composition api.

```
 const  data = computed(() => store.getters['projectSettings/getData']);
```

I get the data via store.getters return it and render it in the template. That works fine.

```
<cc-headline tag="h1">{{ data.name }}</cc-headline>
```

But if I want to use the same piece of data within setup() it is undefined

```
const  data = computed(() => store.getters['projectSettings/getData']);

console.log(data.name)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you return the `data` inside the setup hook?

Comment: Yes I do return it inside the setup. It is rendered in the template

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

```
onUpdated(() => {
      console.log(data.value.name)
    })
```

It is no longer undefined and returns the value from the api

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a computed property in the `setup` function you have to access it with `console.log(data.value.name)`.

In the template it's working, because it automatically resolves to `data.value` if you render it via `{{ data }}`

Check the documentation to learn more: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#standalone-computed-properties

Comment: I also tried this, but it is still undefined

Comment: Can you add the code for the getter and the action, which loads the data?

Comment: According to the updated code, `data` is an Array, isn't it? In the template you treat it like an object. Or is the initialization of `apiData` not correct?